# Python looping issue for short program

Tags: python, loops, break

When I run the below program it does input verification correctly and it performs the Collatz Sequence just fine.  The issue is that it doesn't loop back to the beginning.  I have tried removing the "break" in the second part, I have tried moving the second block around, and other small stuff, but I can't get it to go back to the input again to start over.

```
#Collatz Sequence

import sys

#main part of input and processing number

print ('Collatz Sequence, Y\'all!')

try:
    while True:

        print ('Please type in an integer greater than 1. Type (q) to quit.')
        number = input()
        if number == 'q':
            print ('OK, see ya!')
            sys.exit() # quit the program

        if number.isdecimal() == True: #checks that input is a number
            number = int(number)
            break #breaks out of loop   

    print ('Please type in a number')




    while True:
        maybe = number%2
            #print ('DEBUG ' + 'maybe is ' + str (maybe) + ' number is ' + str (number))

        if number == 1:
            print (' ')
            print (' ')
            print ('Final answer is 1.')
            print (' ')
            print ('Let\'s do it again:')
            print (' ')
            break

        elif maybe == 0:
            print (' ')
            print (str(number) + ' is even.')
            number = number//2

        elif maybe == 1:
            print (' ')
            print (str(number) + ' is odd.')
            number = 3 * number + 1

        print ('Recalculating')

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Please see [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Very little of your posted code is needed to describe the problem -- which I strongly suspect is a variation of several existing questions you should have found already, under the general concept of "how do I make a game repeat?"

Comment: I agree with @Prune, and I’ll add that this seems rather basic. I can’t imagine any future readers will benefit from this.

Answer (score 1):

Try making your logic simpler and you will see your problem.  Your current logic is:

```
try:
    while True:
        <get number>
        if <want to quit>:  sys.exit()
        if <number is good>:  break        
    while True:
        if <done>:  break
        <step>
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.exit()
```

It sounds like you want something more like

```
try:
    while True:
        while True:
            <get number>
            if <want to quit>:  sys.exit()
            if <number is good>:  break
        while True:
            if <done>:  break
            <step>
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.exit()
```

You are confusing the fact that you use loops to get input and calculate the path with needing to use a loop to continue that process.  Functions would make this much more obvious.

Comment: Yes.  Thank you Cireo!  Worked like a charm.  Much appreciated.